# Add "alt" tag to images wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, alt-attribute

I'm trying to solve a situation by creating a code that checks and automatically adds alt tag from the name.
It works partially, that is, it does what it has to do, but whatever I do, I end up consuming resources, in one way or another.
Can someone please lend a hand? I think it is useful to many. It is very helpful when you have many images, in my case 40 k

```
// Set the number of images to process per batch
$batch_size = 2;

// Set the page number to start from
$page_number = 1;

// Set a flag to indicate if there are more images to process
$more_images = true;

// Loop through each batch of images
while ($more_images) {
// Get the current batch of images
$images = get_posts([
"post_type" => "attachment",
"post_mime_type" => "image",
"posts_per_page" => $batch_size,
"orderby" => "ID",
"order" => "DESC",
"paged" => $page_number,
]);
// Check if there are any images in the batch
if (!empty($images)) {
// Initialize an array to store the image IDs and alt tags
$image_data = [];
  // Loop through each image in the batch
  foreach ($images as $image) {
       // Get the image ID
       $post_ID = $image->ID;

       // Check if the image has an empty alt tag
       $alt = get_post_meta($post_ID, "_wp_attachment_image_alt", true);
       if (empty($alt)) {
            // Get the image title
            $my_image_title = get_post($post_ID)->post_title;

            // Sanitize the title: remove hyphens, underscores & extra spaces
            $my_image_title = preg_replace(
                 "%\s*[-_\s]+\s*%",
                 " ",
                 $my_image_title
            );

            // Sanitize the title: capitalize first letter of every word (other letters lower case):
            $my_image_title = ucwords(strtolower($my_image_title));

            // Store the image ID and sanitized title in the image data array
            $image_data[$post_ID] = $my_image_title;
       }

       // Add a 2-second work break between two images
       sleep(2);
  }

  // Update the alt tags for all images in the batch
  foreach ($image_data as $post_ID => $alt_tag) {
       update_post_meta(
            $post_ID,
            "_wp_attachment_image_alt",
            $alt_tag
       );
  }

  // Increment the page number
  $page_number++;
} else {
// Set the flag to indicate that there are no more images to process
$more_images = false;
}

// Pause for a few seconds before moving on to the next batch
sleep(5);
}
```

Comment: Are you running this from your browser or from the CLI?

Comment: I run directly on the site (with a test before in onlinephp.io). I use in Wordpress, Code snippet for  insert. If something goes crazy, it's safer.

Comment: You can improve its performance by removing the sleep function which slows down the processing. Instead, you can set a higher batch size so that you can process more images in one go. This way, you can minimize the number of times you need to perform the query.

Comment: I introduced those limitations precisely because they created problems. Faster after activation. Although the server is quite generous (CPU22.4 GHz = 7, CPU, RAM8 GB) and I have given maximum execution and memory values, I still get a request timeout, 5xx, allowed memory...
At this point I used it to do the piece work.
Even increased max execution time and increased memory, it still reaches the error after a while. During this time, it executes correctly and does what it has to do.

Comment: Personally I'd move this to a background task that operates in batches, `n` at a time, that exists when complete which will release. I'd then optimize the initial query and see if I could query for images without alt at that point instead of additional queries later. If you can't do it in `get_posts`, then write a raw SQL query.